# Should object be created if only static methods are going to be used?

Tags: c#, class, methods, static

If a class contains only static methods, should an object of the class be created in order to utilise the static methods of the class?

eg. if class `MyClass` contains only static methods, which of the following is preferred?

```
MyClass.MyStaticMethod(3);
```

OR

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass(); 
mc.MyStaticMethod(3);
```

Comment: The second example won't even compile.

Answer (score 3):

If they're static, you don't need an instance. You can't do this in C# (correctly - you can in Java and I would suggest that's confusing).

If you *can* instantiate an instance, I would tend towards that solution. If you need to enhance your methods to maintain state, you're going to cause yourself some grief by making these methods static.

Comment: It's not only confusing, it's illegal. The compiler will complain about the second example.

Comment: Ah. Was thinking in the Java world. Will amend

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** call static method like this:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass(); 
mc.MyStaticMethod(3);
```

it won't compile. the only way that you can call the static method is by preceding them with the type name if called outside the class in which they have been implemented.

So you can only call them with `MyClass.MyStaticMethod(3);`

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass.MyStaticMethod(3); is preferred.
```

Also, you want to declare the class as static so it cannot be instantiated by mistake and the intended use is clear

```
public static MyClass
{
public static Property {get;set;}
public static MyMethod() { .... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Contrary what others said in their answers:

You **can't** call static methods on class instances. This will yield a compiler error.

That makes your question kinda pointless, as there is only one option:

```
MyClass.MyStaticMethod(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, no need for a constructor or creating an instance if you only use instance variables or methods

Answer (score 0):

Static members are associated with the class itself **not** it's objects..

it doesn't make sense to access static members through object's and so is an **error**..

You should access static members through class itself

Answer (score 0):

IMHO ,

if the class is having static methods + instance methods and you think only static method is going to be used , i would suggest its time to do refactoring of your code, use "Extract CLass" refactoring to generate a class and make it static and use this static class rather than messing static methods with instance methods if static methods are significant in numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If a class contains only static methods, its better to make the class static too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring all the static methods in side the class then you will have to call the methods using the Class name i.e.

```
 MyClass.MyStaticMethod(3);
```

***And yes you are not able to call static methods by creating the objects of the class***

You don't need to create the object of that class. And if your class contains nothing then the Static Methods you should create it as static class.

You will need the class object for other variables or methods which are non-static.